# Reading from .tfrecord files using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to read the dataset generated by [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_cifar10.py) with the `tf.data.Dataset` api. The repo shows it was written like this:

```
def image_to_tfexample(image_data, image_format, height, width, class_id):
  return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/encoded': bytes_feature(image_data),
      'image/format': bytes_feature(image_format),
      'image/class/label': int64_feature(class_id),
      'image/height': int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': int64_feature(width),
  }))
```

with `(encoded byte-string, b'png', 32, 32, label)` as parameters.

So, to read the .tfrecord file, the data format would have to be:

```
example_fmt = {
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, ""),
    'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, ""),
    'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, -1),
    'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, -1),
    'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, -1)
}
parsed = tf.parse_single_example(example, example_fmt)
image = tf.decode_raw(parsed['image/encoded'], out_type=tf.uint8)
```

But it doesn't work. The dataset is empty after reading and generating an iterator with it raises `OutOfRangeError: End of sequence`.

A short python script for reproduction can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/zEG4GKm9). I'm struggling to find exact documentation or examples for this problem.

Comment: It might help to see more of your code. Are you calling the dataset's map function to parse each example? Are you reading the TFRecord file using GZIP decompression?

Comment: I'm currently only trying to get the dataset to work properly. The code I linked is all I'm working with at the moment. The code that creates the tfrecord in the repo above does not use GZIP to serialise, do I still need it to deserialise properly? And yes, I'm calling the dataset's map function to parse each example with the example format I posted above, to no avail so far. I'm really only looking for a way to parse the examples properly at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test your code because I don't have the train.tfrecords file. Does this code create an empty dataset?

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('train.tfrecords')
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
itr = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(itr.get_next()))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

If this gives you an error, please let me know which line produces it.

Comment: This led me to the solution! `Dataset.list_files().interleave()` only applies a search filter instead of opening files directly. Your code queried the file directly and revealed that the file name was wrong. The download and convert script for the dataset names it `train.tfrecord` (no S) by default. Thus my search pattern did not include the file and therefore I received no input from it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, but it helped me to read and load tagged images (tagged with VoTT) for training YOLOv4/v3. Maybe this code is another "example" that might help someone:

```
def load_single_boxed_tfrecord(record):
"""
Loads a single tfrecord with its boundary boxes and corresponding labels, from a single tfrecord.

Args:
    record: as tfrecord (Tensor), as yielded from tf.data.TFRecordDataset
Returns:
    (Tensor of image), (Tensor of labels), (Tensor of: x_top_left, x_lower_right, y_top_left, y_lower_right)

"""
feature = {'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
           'image/object/class/label': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
           'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
           'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
           'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
           'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
           'image/filename': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
           'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
           }

tf_file = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, feature)

tf_img = tf.image.decode_image(tf_file["image/encoded"], channels=COLOR_CHANNELS)
tf_img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(tf_img, tf.float32)

label = tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_file['image/object/class/label'], default_value=0)
# normalized values:
x1norm = tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_file['image/object/bbox/xmin'], default_value=0)
x2norm = tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_file['image/object/bbox/xmax'], default_value=0)
y1norm = tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_file['image/object/bbox/ymin'], default_value=0)
y2norm = tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_file['image/object/bbox/ymax'], default_value=0)

return tf_img, label, [x1norm, x2norm, y1norm, y2norm]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning TensorFlow and tfrecordfile usage so I'm not a master of these things, but I've found this [guide](https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564) that was useful in my case and might be useful also for you.